How to SOAP with cert without private key
since years we have multiple SOAP interfaces running where the certificate is in .pem format installed in our app. The SOAP suite uses the .pem with the passphrase to connect. Recently the cert is no longer provided by us but by a another party and they are not willing to share the pkey. Which from their standpoint is totally legit but how can we secure our connection without the use of the pkey? They mention connecting with a public key but i cannot find anything on this method. I've read something about x.509 but know not enough to fully comprehend if that would be a solution.
So, to summarize; the SOAP must remain secure but we will not have access to the pkey anymore.
Is there a method to connect securely/authenticated without the pkey?

There are several details that I'm missing here. Are you talking from the perspective of a developer of a SOAP client that must connect to a SOAP service, or are you the developer of the SOAP service?

It is unclear what your setup is. Is this about server authentication, i.e. the normal TLS? The client does not need access to the private key for the server certificate. Or is this about client authentication, i.e. mutual TLS? In this case the client needs to have its own certificate and also matching private key.

I will try to answer. 1) we connect to a service so from this standpoint i would say we are the client, to other party is the server. 2) the SOAP connects using the PHP options 'local_cert' and 'passphrase'. The local_cert points to a .pem file which can be accessed by the passphrase to use the cert and pkey. As i understand the pkey is mandatory in this setup. Which i read all over the topics i find with my keywords (before i posted this). The party supplying the server side is no longer willing to provide a .pem with passphrare holding their pkey.
